# Geforce 7300 LE - Nvidia 304.131 driver crashes in ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have an old Dell Optiplex GX280 whith a PCIe card Nvidia Geforce 7300 LE. I have instaled de latest Nvidia 304.131 driver for this 32 bit achitecture and the driver doesn't work, and the desktop  crashes. This is the desktop:

[image]

The Nvidia Geforce 7300 LE card works fine whith windows 7.

Launching ubuntu whith de Video Integrated Intel Extreme Graphics card works ok, but whith the Nvidia Geforce 7300 LE card and Nvidia 304.131 driver not.

When I try to push on the desktop, compiz run at 100% cpu all the time and it's no posible to use graphic mode.

From comand line [ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1] i've tried to install the old 173 driver but it's no posible due to broken dependencies whith xorg-video-abi-11 to 15.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to uninstall Nvidia drivers using the command below your desktop will be back to default:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

However I'm still searching how install correct drivers for GEForce 7300 LE and solve my problem.

Hug.